# Puppeteer returning undefined (JS) using xPath

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape this element: [image] on [this website](https://magicseaweed.com/Bore-Surf-Report/1886/).

My JS code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const url = 'https://magicseaweed.com/Bore-Surf-Report/1886/'
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);
const title = await page.$x('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/header/h3/div[1]/span[1]')
let text = await page.evaluate(res => res.textContext, title[0])
console.log(text) // UNDEFINED
```

text is undefined. What is the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: try some debugging ... what is the value of `title` or specifically `title[0]` - is it what you expect?

Comment: I think your xpath is incorrect ... it seems to (almost) target the span that says `Current Surf Report for Bore`

Comment: You are right, I had the wrong xpath in there. Updated with the correct one in the question. It still yields undefined. ```console.log(title[0])``` is a huge object of some sort, which I can't make sense out of

Comment: Oh ... one thing I did was remove `/html/body/.....` and changed it to `//body/......` - because the xpath failed when `html` was included - that's why I said your xpath almost targets a particular element

Comment: I see. However, I cannot get '//body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]' to work either. Strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to fix 1 or 2 issues on your code.

1. textContent vs textContext
2. xpath

For the content you want the xpath should be:

```
const title = await page.$x('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/text()')
```

And to get the content of this:

```
const text = await page.evaluate(el => {
    return el.textContent.trim()
}, title[0])
```

Notice you need send title[0] as an argument to the page function.

OR

if you don't need to use xpath, it seems you could get directly using class name to find the element:

```
const rating = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return $('.rating.rating-large.clearfix > li.rating-text')[0].textContent.trim()
})
```